# Wrong answer of R using == operator

Tags: r, vector, boolean

I think R is giving me the wrong output but I don't know why, here is the code:

```
    v=1:52
> v==c(7,8)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[45] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> v==c(4,5)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[45] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

the first output is correct, but why I get falses in the second?

Comment: the second one is recycled to 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5... so it's off by one

Comment: R does as documented. Maybe use `v %in% c(4,5)` and `v %in% c(7,8)`